# resolve()/reject() in Promise executor function: settled immediatly or when executor returns?

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I am new to JavaScript, and I have been trying to wrap my head around Promises.

Given the following:

```js
function asyncDog(ball) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log("Promise() constructor --> executor function \n setting timeout...");
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("resolving...");
      resolve(ball)
      console.log("resolved!")
    }, 2000)
    console.log("Promise() constructor --> executor function \n timeout set!");
  })
}

var promise = asyncDog("ball1")
promise.then((value) => {
  console.log(value);
})
console.log("async function call done")
```

I am aware this should not be how to use a Promise, but I am curious about things...

Why is "resolved!" returned before "ball1"?

The `resolve()` function is actually only called once the executor has returned?

The call to the resolve() function seems to be addressed as if it was `setTimeout(() => {resolve()},)`

Just after the call to `resolve()`, before the next call to `console.log()` in the executor, is the promise settled or still pending?

I can't find the documentation that explains this subtlety.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/Promise

Only says:

> Once resolutionFunc or rejectionFunc is called, the promise's state
> moves from "pending" to either "fulfilled" or "rejected".

Answer (score 4):

> Why is "resolved!" returned before "ball1"?

Because the `resolve()` function does not call `then` callbacks. It merely *schedules* those calls by putting jobs in the promise job queue.

> The `resolve()` function is actually only called once the executor has returned?

Yes, the callback that is passed to `setTimeout` will be called from a job that is scheduled in a queue. Only when JavaScript has completed the execution of the current code and has emptied the callstack will a job be pulled from a job queue, and be executed.

> The call to the `resolve()` function seems to be addressed as if it was `setTimeout(() => {resolve()},)`

No, `resolve` is executed when it is encountered, but it doesn't *synchronously* call the related `then` callbacks. `resolve` will synchronously set the promise's state to resolved, but that will only be notified asynchronously.

> Just after the call to `resolve()`, before the next call to `console.log()` in the executor, is the promise settled or still pending?

It is settled, but there is no way to verify this with JavaScript code. Some implementations of `console`, provided by the host in which JavaScript runs, might be able to show this, but it is not accessible directly via JavaScript code. Your code will get notified asynchronously.

#### References

That the call to `resolve` will synchronously change the promise's state, but will only create asynchronous jobs for calling `then` callbacks, can be found in the ECMAScript Specification.

In [27.2.1.3.2 Promise Resolve Functions](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-promise-resolve-functions), step 6 indicates the change of state:

> 6. Set *alreadyResolved*.[[Value]] to `true`.

For simple resolutions (i.e. resolving with non-thenable), step 8 or 12 is relevant:

> a. Perform FulfillPromise(*promise*, *resolution*).

In [27.2.1.4 FulfillPromise ( promise, value )](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-fulfillpromise) we find in steps 6 and 7:

> 6. Set *promise*.[[PromiseState]] to `fulfilled`.
> 7. Perform TriggerPromiseReactions(*reactions*, *value*).

At [27.2.1.8 TriggerPromiseReactions ( reactions, argument )](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-triggerpromisereactions) we find

> 1.b. Perform HostEnqueuePromiseJob(*job*.[[Job]], *job*.[[Realm]]).

...which means the relevant `then` callbacks will be called from a job in a job queue, which is an asynchronous process.

I ignore here the special treatment that occurs when `resolve` is called with a promise object (or thenable) as argument. In that case, the first promise will only get settled when the second promise is settled.

Comment: "Because the resolve() function does not call then callbacks. It merely schedules those calls by putting jobs in the promise job queue.": it there an official documentation explaining that? Not that I don't trust you :)

Comment: Mozilla Contributers write on the [`then` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then#parameters): *"onFulfilled [is a] Function **asynchronously** called if the Promise is fulfilled."*. More formally in ECMA Script specs, see [Promise Resolve Functions](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-promise-resolve-functions) and [TriggerPromiseReactions](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-triggerpromisereactions)

Comment: I added references to my answer with the relevant quotes.